# Error in error log PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, error-handling

Error in error log but results are showing perfectly I don't know how and why this error is showing up in error file.

**PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** please help me with this How can I get rid of this error?

```
<?php

    $business_name = $value['business_name'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM listings_reviews WHERE business_name = '$business_name' order by listing_date DESC";
    $result = $conn -> query($sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }

    //print_r($row); //exit;
    ?>


    <?php
    foreach ($data as $value){ ?>

    <div class="col-md-12 reviews">
    <span style="color:#000"><?php echo hide_mail ($value['reviewer_email'])?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#000">
    <?php

    $starNumber = $value['rating'];

    //echo $starNumber; exit;

        for($x=1;$x<=$starNumber;$x++) {
            echo '<i style="font-size:12px; color:#00BF9A" class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        }
        if (strpos($starNumber,'.')) {
            echo '<i style="font-size:12px; color:#00BF9A" class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
            $x++;
        }
        while ($x<=5) {
            echo '<i style="font-size:12px; color:#00BF9A" class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
            $x++;
        }
    ?>
    </span> 

    <span style="float:right; color:#666; font-size:14px"><?php echo $value['listing_date']?></span>
    <hr style="margin:5px">
    <span style="color:#666"><?php echo $value['comment']?></span>





    </div>
    <?php
    }  

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases there are no results, so `$data[] = $row;` is never called and `$data` is undefined.

The fix is to properly initialize `$data`:

```
$data = []; // add this

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```